# Is it possible to scale a Neo4j node based on the number of it's relationships?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

Lets say Node1 has 5 relationships to other nodes and Node2 has 10. Can you set the size of each node based on the number of its relationship to other nodes? So in this example, Node2 would be two times the size of Node1.

I saw you can do this manually from the Neo4j Browser-UI but my question is if this is possible to automatically scale when the Nodes are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j Browser does not support this, however, if you use Neo4j Desktop, you can try out the Neo4j Bloom visualization tool, which supports rule-based node size based on the degree of the node. Check out some examples at: https://neo4j.com/bloom/